# how to drop and re-run migrations with db-migrate

Tags: node.js, npm, dbmigrate

I am trying to seed the db before I run all my tests. So I have created a new file `bootstrapTest.js` and included it in my test source file like this `gulp.src(['test/bootstrapTest.js', 'test/**/*.js']`

`bootstrapTest.js` now needs to reset the database and re-run the migrations and seed the data. So I create a child process and let it run a shell script (`seed.sh`).

```
`const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('./seed.sh', 
    {env: {database__host: 'localhost', database__user: 'username', 
    database__port: 3306, database__password: 'password'}}, function 
    (error, stdout, stderr) { ...
}`
```

and this is how my `seed.sh` looks like

`#!/bin/bash
./node_modules/.bin/db-migrate reset --env test
echo '## Database truncated'
./node_modules/.bin/db-migrate up --env test
echo '## Database migrated'`

In the output on the console, I only see the echo output and not the commands that are run. I have validated that indeed db-migrate is not running.

Any idea why `db-migrate` is not running? When I run this manually from my zsh, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out a better way to achieve the same result. Instead of running these via shell script, I added them in my package.json script and run that script before starting the test. So my package.json looks like this

    `"scripts": {
      "testdb": "db-migrate reset --env test && db-migrate up --env test",
      "test": "npm run testdb && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp"
     }`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming,you are running node with [**`npm start`**](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

One can do **db migration** using [**`npm hooks`**](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

```
"scripts" : {
    "prestart":"db-migrate reset --env test && db-migrate up --env test",
    "start" : "node server.js",
    "poststart" :"echo 'do after server run'"
  },
```

In short,

> $. **npm start** //command fired on terminal

```
//output
```

> 1. **npm preinstall** //first to run
> 2. **npm start** //now this

When you do,`npm start`,before it `prestart` script will be executed and then `start` script.